# External hard drive no detected in a vista ultimate

Tags: networking, windows-vista, external-hard-drive

I have created a partition in my external HD and later i am trying to install XP over Vista .
So i have entered into my DOS prompt and i choose the DISK TYPE and i choose external DD and i tried to CLEAN it , Immediately my external HD is asked for FORMAT and i rejected it . After that i restarted my system , therefore i cannot able to see my  external HD on my sysmen

External HD:  Seagate Free agent(500GB)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the drivers for the external HDD is on the HDD itself, and that you no longer can access it because of this.

I had this issue myself when I tried to format one of my own external HDD's.

Try downloading the drivers from the product website